# Only the first row of a table updates after new details are inserted in a popup form

Tags: codeigniter

In each row of a table, I have an “insert” link. When a user clicks this link, a popup window appears containing a form. When the user clicks the “save” button for the form, the form update works only for the first row of the parent table. It takes only the first row ID.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>




    </style>-->
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Popup contact form using only CSS - Demo | CodingCrazy</title>
<link href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/css/styleform.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Electrolize' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />

<!--CC-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/css/fonts.css"/>
</head>


</body>
</html>






<!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php // echo base_url();?>assets/css/special.css" type="text/css" />-->
<div class="bal" style="margin-left: 627px;
    padding: 15px;">


    Balance Amount:<input type="text" name="bal">
    <?php echo form_open('money_c/addrow')?>
    <input type="submit" style="padding:7px;" name="sub" value="add row">

<?php echo form_close();?></div>





<table border="1">


    <tr>
                        <th>Date</th>
               <th>Description</th>
                              <th>Category</th>
                              <th>Debit</th>
                                 <th>Credit</th>
                                    <th>Bal.AMT</th>
                                       <th>Insert</th>
                                       <th> EDit/Delete</th></tr>


           <?php foreach($query2 as $row)
           {

               $date=$row->date;
               $desc=$row->description;
               $credit=$row->credit;
               $deb=$row->debit;
               $bal=$row->bal;
               $cat=$row->category;
               $id=$row->id;

          ?>

                <tr><td><?php echo $date;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $desc;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $credit;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $deb;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $bal;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $cat;?></td>

        <td><a href="#pop" >Insert<div id="pop" class="box">
          <?php


           ?>
<!--<form action="" method="post" class="smart-green">-->
    <div class="smart-green">

    <?php 

    echo form_open('money_c/manualupdatesave/'.$id)?>///here updation happens only for first row id;
    <h1>
        <span>Please fill all the texts in the fields.</span>
    </h1>
    <label>
        <span>Date:</span>
        <input type="date" name="dat"  />
    </label>
      <label>
        <span>Description:</span>
        <input name="desc" type="text" />
    </label>

   <label>
        <span>Category:</span><select name="selection">


        <?php foreach($query1 as $row1)
            {

                $cat=$row1->category;
                ?>
        <!--<option value="Job Inquiry">Job Inquiry</option>-->
        <option value="<?php echo $cat;?>"><?php echo$cat;?></option>

        <?php
            }
            ?>
        </select>
    </label> 

    <label>
        <span>Debit:</span>
        <input type="text" name="deb"></input>
    </label> 
     <label>
        <span>Credit:</span>
        <input type="text" name="credit"></input>
    </label> 

     <label>
        <span>&nbsp;</span> 
        <input type="submit" style="margin-top:12px" class="button" style="background-color: #004e98;"value="Send" /> 
    </label>  
    </div>
<?php echo form_close();?>
<!--</form>-->
<div id="close">


         <td><a href="<?php echo site_url('money_c/manualdelete/'.$id);?>"><img src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/images/del.jpg" width="60" height="40"></a></td>



                </tr>
                <?php
           }
           ?></table>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

My controller:

```
money_c
 function manualupdatesave($id)
    {

       $a=$this->input->post('dat');
        $b=$this->input->post('desc');
        $c=$this->input->post('cat');
          $d=$this->input->post('deb');
            $e=$this->input->post('credit');
        $this->money_m->transaction($a,$b,$c,$d,$e,$id);

         $this->load->view('header'); 
        $result['query2'] = $this->money_m->selecttrans();


         $this->load->view('manualupdate',$result);     
         $this->load->view('footer');





    }
```

view page: `manualupdate.php`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>




    </style>-->
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Popup contact form using only CSS - Demo | CodingCrazy</title>
<link href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/css/styleform.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Electrolize' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />

<!--CC-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/css/fonts.css"/>
</head>






<!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php // echo base_url();?>assets/css/special.css" type="text/css" />-->
<div class="bal" style="margin-left: 627px;
    padding: 15px;">


    Balance Amount:<input type="text" name="bal">
    <?php echo form_open('money_c/addrow')?>
    <input type="submit" style="padding:7px;" name="sub" value="add row">

<?php echo form_close();?></div>





<table border="1">


    <tr>
                        <th>Date</th>
               <th>Description</th>
                              <th>Category</th>
                              <th>Debit</th>
                                 <th>Credit</th>
                                    <th>Bal.AMT</th>
                                       <th>Insert</th>
                                       <th> EDit/Delete</th></tr>


           <?php foreach($query2 as $row)
           {

               $date=$row->date;
               $desc=$row->description;
               $credit=$row->credit;
               $deb=$row->debit;
               $bal=$row->bal;
               $cat=$row->category;
               $id=$row->id;

          ?>

                <tr><td><?php echo $date;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $desc;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $credit;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $deb;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $bal;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $cat;?></td>

        <td><a href="#pop" >Insert<div id="pop" class="box">
          <?php


           ?>
<!--<form action="" method="post" class="smart-green">-->
    <div class="smart-green">

    <?php 

    echo form_open('money_c/manualupdatesave/'.$id)?>
    <h1>
        <span>Please fill all the texts in the fields.</span>
    </h1>
    <label>
        <span>Date:</span>
        <input type="date" name="dat"  />
    </label>
      <label>
        <span>Description:</span>
        <input name="desc" type="text" />
    </label>

   <label>
        <span>Category:</span><select name="selection">


        <?php foreach($query1 as $row1)
            {

                $cat=$row1->category;
                ?>
        <!--<option value="Job Inquiry">Job Inquiry</option>-->
        <option value="<?php echo $cat;?>"><?php echo$cat;?></option>

        <?php
            }
            ?>
        </select>
    </label> 

    <label>
        <span>Debit:</span>
        <input type="text" name="deb"></input>
    </label> 
     <label>
        <span>Credit:</span>
        <input type="text" name="credit"></input>
    </label> 

     <label>
        <span>&nbsp;</span> 
        <input type="submit" style="margin-top:12px" class="button" style="background-color: #004e98;"value="Send" /> 
    </label>  
    </div>
<?php echo form_close();?>
<!--</form>-->
<div id="close">


         <td><a href="<?php echo site_url('money_c/manualdelete/'.$id);?>"><img src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/images/del.jpg" width="60" height="40"></a></td>



                </tr>
                <?php
           }
           ?></table>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

My popup form:

```
 <?php 

    echo form_open('money_c/manualupdatesave/'.$id)?>
    <h1>
        <span>Please fill all the texts in the fields.</span>
    </h1>
    <label>
        <span>Date:</span>
        <input type="date" name="dat"  />
    </label>
      <label>
        <span>Description:</span>
        <input name="desc" type="text" />
    </label>

   <label>
        <span>Category:</span><select name="selection">


        <?php foreach($query1 as $row1)
            {

                $cat=$row1->category;
                ?>
        <!--<option value="Job Inquiry">Job Inquiry</option>-->
        <option value="<?php echo $cat;?>"><?php echo$cat;?></option>

        <?php
            }
            ?>
        </select>
    </label> 

    <label>
        <span>Debit:</span>
        <input type="text" name="deb"></input>
    </label> 
     <label>
        <span>Credit:</span>
        <input type="text" name="credit"></input>
    </label> 

     <label>
        <span>&nbsp;</span> 
        <input type="submit" style="margin-top:12px" class="button" style="background-color: #004e98;"value="Send" /> 
    </label>  
    </div>
<?php echo form_close();?>
```

Comment: Anyone please answer this question

Comment: why is this tagged javascript?

Comment: Please make your question formatting properly. Which is your controller file ? what view you are using etc. so its easy to read and understand to others

Comment: sir i added above 'my controller'    and 'view page'

Comment: I am unable to understand your view. Where its start? where is popup ? Make it proper readable so that someone can help.

Comment: pop up form i added above,in that money_c/manualupdatesave/'.$id  is taking only first row id...so updation happens only for first row.

Comment: print $id in your controller and check what id you are getting fro different rows update

Comment: possible duplicate of [i cant update by inserting pop up form details,using codeigniter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31783080/i-cant-update-by-inserting-pop-up-form-details-using-codeigniter)

Comment: @Anbarasan. If I'm reading this correctly, there's a popup form, which, when saved, should cause the parent page to update. That's probably using javascript, so a javascript tag would seem appropriate. On the other hand, no javascript code has been shown.