# I cannot update by inserting details from a popup form

Tags: codeigniter

When I click the insert link in the second row it passes the ID of the first. Only the first row is updated.

My controller: `money_c`:

```
function addrow()
    {
        $this->load->view('header');
        $this->load->view('manualupdate',$result);
        $this->load->view('footer');
    }
```

My view page: `manualupdate.php`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

        </style>-->
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Popup contact form using only CSS - Demo | CodingCrazy</title>
    <link href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/css/styleform.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Electrolize' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />

    <!--CC-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/css/fonts.css"/>
    </head>

    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php // echo base_url();?>assets/css/special.css" type="text/css" />-->
    <div class="bal" style="margin-left: 627px;
        padding: 15px;">

    <table border="1">

        <tr>
                            <th>Date</th>
                   <th>Description</th>
                                  <th>Category</th>
                                  <th>Debit</th>
                                     <th>Credit</th>
                                        <th>Bal.AMT</th>
                                           <th>Insert</th>
                                           <th> EDit/Delete</th></tr>

               <?php foreach($query2 as $row)
               {

                   $date=$row->date;
                   $desc=$row->description;
                   $credit=$row->credit;
                   $deb=$row->debit;
                   $bal=$row->bal;
                   $cat=$row->category;
                   $id=$row->id;

              ?>

                    <tr><td><?php echo $date;?></td>
            <td><?php echo $desc;?></td>
            <td><?php echo $credit;?></td>
            <td><?php echo $deb;?></td>
            <td><?php echo $bal;?></td>
            <td><?php echo $cat;?></td>

           <td><a href="#pop" >Insert<div id="pop" class="box">////here pop up will come////pop up starts
</tr>
                    <?php
               }
               ?></table>

        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Popup:

```
<div class="smart-green">

    <?php

     echo
        form_open('money_c/manualupdatesave/'.$id)?>

            <label>
            <span>Date:</span>
            <input type="date" name="dat"  />
        </label>
          <label>
            <span>Description:</span>
            <input name="desc" type="text" />
        </label>

        <label>
            <span>Debit:</span>
            <input type="text" name="deb"></input>
        </label> 
         <label>
            <span>Credit:</span>
            <input type="text" name="credit"></input>
        </label> 

         <label>
            <span>&nbsp;</span>
            <input type="submit" style="margin-top:12px" class="button" style="background-color: #004e98;"value="Send" />
        </label>
        </div>
    <?php echo form_close();?>//////pop up ends///////////
    <!--</form>-->
    <div id="close">
```

model: `money_m`:

```
    function transaction($a,$b,$c,$d,$e,$id)
    {
        $this->db->where('id',$id);
        $this->db->set('date',$a);
        $this->db->set('description',$b);
        $this->db->set('debit',$d);
        $this->db->set('credit',$e);
//        $data=array('date'=>$a,'description'=>$b,'debit'=>$d,'credit'=>$e);

        $this->db->update('manualupdate');

    }
```

In `form_open('money_c/manualupdatesave/'.$id)` I get only the first row ID, not the ID of the second row.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31779792/i-cant-update-each-parent-table-row-after-inserting-new-details-in-pop-up-form-u#31779792
don't need to ask new question you can edit old one properly

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="#pop" >Insert<div id="pop" class="box">
```

change this line to

```
<a href="#pop-<?php echo $id;?>" >Insert<div id="pop" class="box">
```

You you popup code is still not complete (assuming it should look like this)

```
<div id="#pop-<?php echo $id;?>">
 <?php 



     echo
        form_open('money_c/manualupdatesave/'.$id)?>



            <label>
            <span>Date:</span>
            <input type="date" name="dat"  />
        </label>
          <label>
            <span>Description:</span>
            <input name="desc" type="text" />
        </label>


        <label>
            <span>Debit:</span>
            <input type="text" name="deb"></input>
        </label> 
         <label>
            <span>Credit:</span>
            <input type="text" name="credit"></input>
        </label> 

         <label>
            <span>&nbsp;</span> 
            <input type="submit" style="margin-top:12px" class="button" style="background-color: #004e98;"value="Send" /> 
        </label>  
        </div>
    <?php echo form_close();?>//////pop up ends///////////
    <!--</form>-->
    <div id="close">
```